# How to add widgets to QToolbox item

Tags: qt, toolbox

I need to auto generate some UI forms in code to display message contents.
I want to use QToolbox, with an item for each message type. I then want to add labels and line edit to the contents of each tab, depending on the message protocol. I cannot seem to programaticaly add widget items to the toolbox item.

Below is my current code segment. The ui->frame is just a container for the toolbox. I will worry later about layout.

In my code, I create a frame and then some labels with parent set to the frame. Then I add the frame as an item to the toolbox.

```
QToolBox *qtbMainToolbox = new QToolBox(ui->frame);;
qtbMainToolbox->setGeometry(0,0,2000,900);
QFrame *frm1 = new QFrame;
QLabel *lbl1 = new QLabel(frm1);
QLabel *lbl2 = new QLabel(frm1);
QLabel *lbl3 = new QLabel(frm1);
QLabel *lbl4 = new QLabel(frm1);
iRetVal - qtbMainToolbox->addItem(frm1 ,"Test");
```

Comment: And what the problem of the code above?

Comment: Good question. ;>) the labels do not appear on the form (in the "Test" portion of toolbox frame).

Comment: And the label does not appear because you don't set text on the label?
And another thing is you need to set the layout on frame instead of just create label with parent label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no visible element in your widgets; icon or any text.

You have to Set icon or Text to Your QLabel.

```
QToolBox *qtbMainToolbox = new QToolBox(ui->frame);;
qtbMainToolbox->setGeometry(0,0,2000,900);
QFrame *frm1 = new QFrame;
QLabel *lbl1 = new QLabel("Hello World",frm1);
iRetVal - qtbMainToolbox->addItem(frm1 ,"Test");
```

try above code.